# Ionic livereload to root page but need to last loaded page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working with ionic application, ionic `CLi 4.5.0`
I am using using `ionic serve` & open preview in browser & when edit any file live reload load to root page but I need to load last woreking/loaded page
suppose root page is home so liveload always load at `http://localhost:8100/#/home`
if my last working/open page is `http://localhost:8100/#/login` and I make change in any file liveload still load at `http://localhost:8100/#/home` but I need to load at `http://localhost:8100/#/login`

Comment: Do you have session based login? Or else if you are using any authorization header for the requests, please store it session storage in ionic and check in login page ionViewDidEnter method and navigate. It should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

It will always load the rootpage which you configured in your app.compontent.ts. If it is text change, it will do a hot-reload feature. If you make any changes in your component, it will restart from the root page. 
The simple way to do is to store the session in observable object or session storage after successful login.

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.storage.get(LOCALSTORAGE.TOKEN).then((val) => {
        if (val)
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
    });
}
```

Using an observable object,

```
  private tokenString: BehaviorSubject<string>;
  setTokenObject(val) {
    if (val)
      this.tokenString.next(val);
    else
      console.log(val);
  }

  getTokenObject() {
    return this.tokenString.asObservable();
  }
```

Updating the token in login success for the first time

```
this.tokenString.next(token); // here token should read it from your login response
```

Hope this helps!